# Sort by embedded document field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following document

[image: Document Picture]

Previously I didn't have the embedded document `vdata` and I had a field named timestamp and when I ran the query below I got the latest entry.

```
db.TagValues.aggregate({$match: {tagDetail: "UMIS.99TOTMW.F_CV"}}, {$sort: {timestamp: -1}}, {$limit: 1})
```

How do I amend the above query to show the same result based on the format of my new document.  I have tried the following but I get a syntax error.

```
db.TagValues.aggregate({$match: {t: "UMIS.99TOTMW.F_CV"}}, {$sort: {vdata.d: -1}}, {$limit: 1})
```

Comment: Use double quotes for the nested fields `{$sort: {"vdata.d": -1}}`

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet that worked thanks, post as answer and I will confirm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double quotes for the nested fields

```
{ "$sort": {"vdata.d": -1}}
```